# Bamboo doesn't recognize test in my Spring project

Tags: maven, testing, junit, bamboo

I have a Spring project (Apache CXF, Spring, Hibernate, Maven ...) hosted on BitBucket and I'm trying to use Bamboo as my CI server. My idea is deploying the code directly to Heroku from Bamboo so that deploying time is automated.

I made a plan with  a couple of tasks to achieve this. First I have a Source Code Checkout task and a builder task. Both of them are working, code is compiling and test are passing, I can see that in the task log. The problem is that Bamboo doesn't  seem to recognize the tests (it marks the task are testless).

I have also tried to create a new JUnit test task and it's even worst.  Log shows that everything is working properly but Bamboo marks the plan as a failure after the test task is executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which version of Bamboo you're using, but in the version that we have, you have to turn on unit test result evaluation on the `Builder` tab. Please see the attached screenshot, and make sure that this is enabled, and the directory setting is pointing to the directory where Maven Surefire creates the test results (in XML format).
[image]

Comment: Hi nwinkler, you gave me the solution but it wasn't because the area you marked with a red square. I had already marked it.The key was that I had to add to the maven goal the java property you use.

Comment: Good to hear that! I'm glad I included that part of the screenshot :-)